# how to add created objects in static array?

Tags: ruby, class, oop

How can i add all created objects in `self.persons` ?

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :last_name, :age
  def initialize(name, last_name, age = "no_age")
    @@persons = []
    @name = name
    @last_name = last_name
    @age = age
    add(@name, @last_name, @age)
  end

  def self.persons
    @@persons
  end

  private
  def add(name, last_name, age)
    @@persons << [name, last_name, age]
  end
end

person1 = Person.new("name1", "lastname1", 12)
person2 = Person.new("name2", "lastname2", 16)

p Person.persons # => [["name2", "lastname2", 16]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "conditional assignment operator" to check if array is nil.

```
def initialize(name, last_name, age = "no_age")
    @@persons ||= []
    @name = name
    @last_name = last_name
    @age = age
    add(@name, @last_name, @age)
  end
```